# Is the jump upgrade required to get the tranquilizer rifle in Deus Ex missing link dlc?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution, the-missing-link

I tried my best with the 2 boxes available but so far I had to get the upgrade to jump on the cargo section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jump upgrade is the easiest way to obtain it, but not the only way. A couple other ways:

- Using the Icarus Landing System
- Stacking three or more boxes to allow you to survive the fall. More items can be found down the adjacent shaft

[Source](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Tranquilizer_rifle#Locations)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by surviving the fall since that is not really an issue. I did find more boxes in the stasis pod area but I have to to back track my save a bit to make that possible. I decided to just get the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand which fall SaintWacko means, but I definitely was able to get to the spot of the Tranquilizer Rifle (behind the stasis pod) by using the two boxes in a very similiar way like in this [achievement guide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kCLSUFFgos8&hd=1) for [Never Forget](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Never_Forget) on YouTube. No augmentations are needed because this one can be achieved as one of nine available [Factory Zero](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Factory_Zero)-playthrough achievements.